# comment & markup toolbar customize to add some button in acrobat 2017

Tags: plugins, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

did adobe 2017 standard allow me to customizing the group comment & mark up toolbar?

and can I add some button I've used to add to the comment & markup toolbar in adobe 2017?

I've been tried wrote the script with JavaScript and C++ to make some button then try with sample plugin from Acrobat SDK, and add it on comment and markup toolbar  like this.. I was add it on Acrobat 9

[my plugin attach on toolbar comment and markup in Adobe Acrobat 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xROH2.png)

but, I've tried to attach my plugin in comment and markup toolbar, my plugin not attach properly in comment toolbar, and it shown separately from default toolbar like this

[adobe 2017 standard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6PCF.png)

is this kind a restriction in the adobe acrobat 2017?

how can we overcome this restriction?